# KeysPressed is bitmasked. How do I un-bitmask and make it into a structure of key states? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, math

So I get the button inputs from the switch sent to my node.js TCP server.
Its a single number but when pressing multiple buttons they are added together.
The joystick positions are not part of this data set.
How would I change KeysPressed back into a structure of key states?
Preferably in javascript as I am using node.js

Here is an example of what I mean
The button numbers are as follows. I do notice the pattern obviously, but I'm not sure how I can translate this into multiple key presses in javascript.

```
A = 1
B = 2
X = 4
Y = 8
LanalogPress = 16
RanalogPress = 32
L = 64
R = 128
ZL = 256
ZR = 512
+ = 1024
- = 2048
DpadL = 4096
DpadU = 8192
DpadRight = 16384
DpadDown = 32768
```

Now if I press down say A and X then KeysPressed = 5. Because 1 + 4 is five of course.

If its + and x then it is KeysPressed = 1028. And so on.

I have never come accross this type of problem and would love to learn why it's done this way and what the solution to this problem is. It's not an easy one to google for sure lol

Comment: Looks to me like it's a bit mask of 16 bits. So 5 would be 0000000000000101 and the sequence of buttons in the OP aligns with the bits from right to left. So the right-most part 101 (4 + 1 = 5) aligns with X and A. That should be all you need to know.

Comment: @RobG I was concerned I wouldn't get it At first but my god I think you made me have the "Ahahhh!" moment!

Thanks. I'll update a solution in a moment

Comment: @RobG nvm I failed in figuring it out still. Think you can lend a hand?

Comment: There are many [questions on bitwise operators](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+bitwise) with good answers, have a browse. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with it forever. I finally found a solution.

I stared at the numbers a while after learning they were bitmasked. Still not entirely sure if I undid the bitmask right. Or that i'm using the word right...

But I noticed that all numbers of inputs that were true were odd. So I just checked if they are odd. It works perfectly even if i don't entirely understand what I did...

If someone can explain why this worked to me that would be great XD

```
function isOdd(int) {
  return (int & 1) === 1;
}
function bitMaskToStruct(HeldKeys) {
  return {
    A: isOdd(HeldKeys >> 0),
    B: isOdd(HeldKeys >> 1),
    X: isOdd(HeldKeys >> 2),
    Y: isOdd(HeldKeys >> 3),
    LS: isOdd(HeldKeys >> 4),
    RS: isOdd(HeldKeys >> 5),
    L: isOdd(HeldKeys >> 6),
    R: isOdd(HeldKeys >> 7),
    ZL: isOdd(HeldKeys >> 8),
    ZR: isOdd(HeldKeys >> 9),
    Plus: isOdd(HeldKeys >> 10),
    Minus: isOdd(HeldKeys >> 11),
    Left: isOdd(HeldKeys >> 12),
    Up: isOdd(HeldKeys >> 13),
    Right: isOdd(HeldKeys >> 14),
    Down: isOdd(HeldKeys >> 15)
  };
}
console.log(bitMaskToStruct(HeldKeys))
```

Comment: You should really have updated your OP with that. But anyway, the [`>>` right shift operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Right_shift)  discards the right–most bit. I'll put an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a bit mask, where the 1s are "on" and 0s are "off". The number 5 in binary is 101, so read from right to left it means the first value (A) is "on", second value (B) is "off" and third value (X) is "on".

Similarly 9 is 1001 so A on, B off, X off and Y on.

The bitwise right shift operator discards the rightmost bit of the number and shifts everything to the right, so `5 >> 1` shifts just one bit, so `101` becomes `10` or 2. You can loop over the number shifting it one bit at a time and testing for odd/even to see if the last digit is 1 (odd) or 0 (even) until you run out of bits, or run over the properties and turn them on or off as you've done.

E.g.

```js
// Decode number n to state
function decodeMask(n) {
  let props = ['A','B', 'X', 'Y', 'LanalogPress', 'RanalogPress', 'L', 'R', 'ZL', 'ZR', '+', '-', 'DpadL', 'DpadU', 'DpadRight', 'DpadDown'];
  // Use empty object so no key clash. Note, doesn't have toString method!
  let state = Object.create(null);
  props.forEach((key, i) => state[key] = !!((n>>i) % 2));
  return state;
}

// Stuff to play with decodeMask
function handleClick(evt) {
  let inp = document.getElementById('inp0');
  let res = document.getElementById('mask');
  let state = document.getElementById('state');
  let n = Number(inp.value);
  let s = decodeMask(n);
  res.textContent = n.toString(2).padStart(Object.keys(s).length,'0');
  state.textContent = Object.keys(s).reduce((acc, key) => {
    acc.push(key + ': ' + s[key]);
    return acc;
  },[]).join('\n'); 
}

window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('btn0').addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);
}

// console.log(decodeMask(5));
```

```html
<input id="inp0"> Enter number<br>
<button id="btn0">getState</button><br>
<div>Mask:&nbsp;<span id="mask"></span></div>
<pre id="state"></pre>
```

I've pretty much copied your method, but you can also do things like just get the "on" buttons:

```js
// Return state object
let n = 9; // 1001
let props = ['A', 'B', 'X', 'Y']; // and so on
for (var state = {}, i = 0; n; i++) {
  if (n % 2) state[props[i]] = 'on';
  n = n >> 1;
}
console.log(state);

// Return just the "on" props
let v = 9; // 1001
let s = props.filter((prop, i) => (v >> i) % 2);
console.log(s);
```

I'm sure there are much funkier ways of going about it, but you've got to keep it maintainable and it depends on what you want the result to be so you can use it for whatever else.